# How do I pass a double array from PHP to C#

Tags: c#, php

I have a .net C# function that takes an double array as the first parameter and passes back another double precision array based on the first.

C# Code

```
public int testMath(double[] InputSet, double[] OutputSet)
{
    // more complicated than what I am showing but
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
      OutputSet[i] = InputSet[i] * 2.0;
   }
   return 1;  // Really something else
}
```

PHP

```
$mathTest = new DOTNET("MathTest,"
        ."Version=1.0.0.0,"
        ."Culture=neutral,"
        ."PublicKeyToken=213536b1e6bb8ea5"
        , "MathTest.MathTest");

$inputValue = Array();
$outputValue = Array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
  $inputValue[$i] = $i * 3.0;
  $outputValue[$i] = 0.0;
}

$status = $mathTest->testMath($inputValue, $outputValue);
```

When I try to run this I get an error that parameter 1 is a type mismatch.
I have other routines that take doubles as inputs and by ref outputs that work as I would expect.  I can call this routine from other programming languages but I am stumped as to how to get it to work in PHP.  I tried viewing the parameters using com_print_typeinfo and found that both arguments show up as VT_SAFEARRAY as IN.  I did some testing to change argument 1 to be an OUT and it made it worse (won't run at all).  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, why does it need to happen in C#? Or the other way round? This seems like a terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most simple approch imo would be to encode the double array as json.

from php

```
json_encode ($myarr);
```

or

```
  json_decode ($myarr); // if u want the other direction
```

and then just catch it in the c# (or vice versa) and decode it.
u can use json.net or jsonFx etc.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I had not use json before so I had to install it on my Visual Studio configuration.  After a few misteps I got it to work.